# How to Identify Safari Javascript Alert Dialog using AppleScript?

Tags: safari, applescript

In a particularly 'pesky' website, a dialog box pops up to block (or cover) automated entry of the userid input box.

I have used the following code attempting to get a reference & to close this window, but have been unsuccessful.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 15 using {command down}
    key code 36        // return key

end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set numSheets to (count of sheets) & " sheets" as text       // 0 sheets
end tell

set numDocuments to (count of documents) & " documents" as text  // 1 documents
set numWindows to (count of windows) & " windows" as text        // 1 sheets
```

What else is available to find and close that alert box?

Edit: The `key code 36` will sometimes close the alert, and other times, when it's not present, will submit the page too early.

Comment: Is the "dialog box" being rendered by the OS or the browser? Stated another way, can you drag the "dialog box" out of the browser window?

Comment: Great question. It can be pulled outside the confines of the Safari window. I have found the alert message in code in an included .js file on the page.

Comment: So you are visiting a website that has an input field for userid but the website is launching an alert window over the input field to obscure it?

Comment: Yes. Intermittently. The alert is saying that some part of a java applet did not load.

Comment: So if you close the alert window you can then log in okay? Have you tried to contact the people who maintain the website to suggest they fix it?

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's the site of a Brazilian government bank. ...haha.  Other alternatives are to contact them and ask about an API or to find my own fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had an alert dialog appearing with an OK button, then this AppleScript code would close it.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    if exists (button "OK" of window 1) then
        click (button "OK" of window 1)
    end if
end tell
```

You'll likely need to customise this to fit your exact situation. If the alert dialog appears with a title you can all specify that as below.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    if exists (button "OK" of window "Java applet missing") then
        click (button "OK" of window "Java applet missing")
    end if
end tell
```

Another option would be to identify the alert by using "front window" as in the following example (assuming the alert is the front window).

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    if exists (button "OK" of front window) then
        click (button "OK" of front window)
    end if
end tell
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I will play with that. What if the alert has NO title?

Comment: Assuming you only have one Safari window open, then the first example where you just specify the index of the window should work.

Comment: The first example works. Could the number of windows always = 1 (previously) because the question above (count of windows) is inside `tell application "Safari"` ?

Comment: The number of windows will change. It is simply what it seems, a count of the open windows. So if you have one window open, then "count of windows" will return 1. If an alert window opens, then "count of windows" will return 2. Note that the windows are indexed from zero. So the first window is 0. The second is 1. And so forth...

Comment: I've updated the answer with another option ("front window") for identifying the alert window.